# node aliased path as views contextual filter

Tags: views

I want to have a view which would output a node title and use a contextual filter the aliased path of a node

```
/nodefilter?url=/category/path-to-article
```

I see there no php contextual filters in drupal 8 anymore do I have to write a custom contextual filter or is there another solution ? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have created a view that uses contextual filter `content ID` to filter the results by "node id" and can be called like this

```
/nodefilter/[NID]
```

After I made sure the view was working I modified the `content ID` contextual filter adding default query paramenter named `url` under `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE > Provide default value`

[image]

then in a custom module used the views api `hook_views_pre_view` as follows

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
function MODULENAME_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if($view->id() == 'view_machine_name'){
    $url = \Drupal::request()->query->get('url');
    $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($url);
    if(preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
      //$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($matches[1]);
      //$nid = $matches[1];
      $args[0] = $matches[1];    
    }    
  }
}
```

Now the view works with `NID` or the `url` parameter

```
/nodefilter/[NID]
/nodefilter/?url=/category/path-to-article
```